# Failed to load assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Fakes

Tags: c#, mstest, microsoft-fakes

I am using Visual Studio 2022 (Professional). When I am trying to run MSTests for C# project I got this message in log.

> Failed to load assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Fakes

Project use .NETFramework 4.8 and this nuget packages

```
<package id="Microsoft.TestPlatform.ObjectModel" version="17.0.0" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="MSTest.TestAdapter" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="MSTest.TestFramework" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net48" />
```

I tried reinstall nuget packages, restore project from scraps, reinstall visual studio. Nothing work. Every test is failed due to insufficient dependencies.

Also I was looking for TestPlatform.Fakes but I cannot find it in nuget repos.

Comment: Which version of NET are you using?

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro It is .NETFramework 4.8

Comment: read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/isolating-code-under-test-with-microsoft-fakes?view=vs-2022